# syntax error: 'delimiter ' is not valid input here

Tags: mysql

I have an error in my `stored procedure` using (mysql 5.6). and I am using Workbench 6.3 CE. My code is as below

```
DELIMITER //            (this line shows error)why??
CREATE PROCEDURE Demo(in v_id int)
BEGIN

select name from student where id=v_id;

END//

delimiter;
```

Comment: Try
    DELIMITER //  
CREATE PROCEDURE Demo(in v_id int)  
BEGIN  
SELECT name from student where id=v_id;  
END //  
DELIMITER;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is not the line

```
DELIMITER //
```

but the line

```
delimiter;
```

You've left out a space; it should be

```
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Demo(in v_id int)
BEGIN
SELECT name from student where id=v_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Your exact statement returns the exact same error as mine. There should be something wrong with my version or something. Is this DELIMITER statement is usable for MySQL?